# Place button inside input

Tags: html, css

I need to place a button, with an icon, an input so I tried the HTML:

(JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/zup3b24e/12/):

```
<form>       
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

With the following CSS:

```
form {
  width: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

But this does not place the button inside the input.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `bottom: 8px;` to the button so it is moved up by `8px`, visually into the input box.

```
button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>       
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zup3b24e/14/

Comment: Why 8px? And why the icon is not aligned to the right of the input when I am using  right: 0?

Comment: @MiguelMoura With `8px` the button is visually inside the input box, like I said. You can try playing with this value. About your other question, that is because you have set your form width to be `400px` but your input box in `424px` which includes the padding. You can fix this by applying `box-sizing: border-box` to the input. I would also make the button background `transparent` so it doesn't overlap with the border of the input. [Check out this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zup3b24e/25/). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to build an input form with font awesome inside if you want to go with this direction

```css
input[type="text"] {
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text"><input type="submit" value="&#xf002;">
```